# What can I implement pointer to strings effectivelyin c using function?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, reverse

I am not able to do this question apart from reading all the theory part.
Write a program to reverse the strings stored in the following
array of pointers to strings:

```
char *s[ ] = {
"To err is human...",
"But to really mess things up...",
"One needs to know C!!"
} ;
```

here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{    int i;
    char *s[] = {
                 "To err is human...",
                 "But to really mess things up...",
                 "One needs to know C!!"
                 } ;
     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
    xstrrev(s[i]);
    puts(s[i]);
     }
return 0;
}
xstrrev(char *str )
{
    char *temp[];
    int len,j;
    len=strlen(str);
    for(j=0;j<(len)/2;j++)
        {

        *temp=*(str+len-j-1);
        *(str+len-j-1)=*(str+j);
        *(str+j)=*temp;

        }
}
```

Comment: What happens? What does not happen? Why do you think that you are unable to answer the question? And what does your question have to do with "effectively"?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what problems you are having. However, I'll point out a few things:

1. You are creating constant strings in your `main`. Depending on what environment you are coding for, those constant strings might get placed into really constant memory. (For example: ROM.) As a result, you should probably either `strdup` or `malloc` the reversed strings.
2. In your `xstrrev` function, you seem a bit confused about the basic types. Remember that a "string" in C is just a whole bunch of `char` objects next to each other, with a sentinel value marking the end. If you are going to swap two `char` objects, you don't need to store indirectly through a pointer, you can just say `char temp;` and later say `temp = *ptr;`
3. For efficiency, as well as your own sanity, I'd suggest that you create a second pointer in `xstrrev`. Call it `char * end` and do the math to make it point to the end of the string. Then you can adjust your swap pointers with just `++str; --end;` and not have all those expressions laying around, each one a potential source of error.

Answer (score 0):

The declared array

```
char *s[ ] = {
"To err is human...",
"But to really mess things up...",
"One needs to know C!!"
} ;
```

is an array of pointers to string literals. You may not change string literals because they are immutable in C and C++. Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behaviour of the program.

Declare the array as a two dimensional array the following way

```
char s[ ][32]  = {
"To err is human...",
"But to really mess things up...",
"One needs to know C!!"
} ;
```

If you mean to reverse the pointers that point to the string literals then you can indeed reverse them that is reverse the order of the strings pointed to by  elements of the array.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how to reverse each string stored in a two-dimensional array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++  )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char s[][32] = 
    {
        "To err is human...",
        "But to really mess things up...",
        "One needs to know C!!"
    };

    const size_t N = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s );

    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) puts( s[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) puts( reverse( s[i] ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
To err is human...
But to really mess things up...
One needs to know C!!

...namuh si rre oT
...pu sgniht ssem yllaer ot tuB
!!C wonk ot sdeen enO
```

As for the function `xstrrev`

```
xstrrev(char *str )
{
    char *temp[];
    int len,j;
    len=strlen(str);
    for(j=0;j<(len)/2;j++)
        {

        *temp=*(str+len-j-1);
        *(str+len-j-1)=*(str+j);
        *(str+j)=*temp;

        }
}
```

then it is invalid and new compilers will not compile it. First of all the function does not have the return type.
This declaration of an array

```
    char *temp[];
```

is invalid because the number of elements is omitted. The variable strlen is not declared.

Comment: Also the declaration of the strings is already given in the pointer form in the question and i have to solve it in that way only.